# Saving functions in a class C++

Tags: c++, c, class, function, iostream

I am a total noob.

I have created functions for int to string and string to int conversion.

I want to save them so I can use them in any program, so I can call them like `#include <iostream>`

Do I do this by creating a class ( which then has no private member variables?)

and if I do it as a class how do I use functions without creating objects?

Basically I want to create my own cmath or string sort of thing but I don't even know what to call it to find out how to make it.

Comment: You don't need classes for everything in C++. You can just use non-member functions (usually, inside of a namespace to avoid name collisions). Also note that the C++ standard library already provides the functionality you mention.

Comment: Free functions is fine, but a namespace wrapper would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just simple functions you can put them in a namespace, which also acts like a container, then put them in a seperate cpp file together and create a `.h` file which contains the prototypes.

i.E for mymath.h:

```
#ifndef MYMATH_H
#define MYMATH_H

namespace mymath
{
     int dosomething(int y);
}

#endif
```

and in the mymath.cpp:

```
#include "mymath.h"

int mymath::dosomething(int y)
{
}
```

Then, when you want to use it, you include your `#include "mymath.h"` file and link the cpp to your project.

Comment: You forgot `#include "mymath.h"` in the mymath.cpp. Also, `int mymath::dosomething(int y)` in definition

Comment: This seems to e on the right track, now I have the issue of inttostring working but stringtoint is underlined in red(visual express 2010) and the error is "expression must have a point to type function"

Comment: fixed it by changing int stringtoint(string) in the header file to int stringtoint(string word), thanks

Answer (score -1):

*mystring.hpp*

```
#ifndef MYSTRING_HPP
#define MYSTRING_HPP

#include <string>

namespace n_mystring
{
    std::string & IntToString( int Int );
    int StringToInt( std::string & String );
}

#endif
```

*mystring.cpp*

```
#include "mystring.hpp"

std::string & n_mystring::IntToString( int Int ) {
    //.... implementation
};

int n_mystring::StringToInt( std::string & String ) {
    //.... implementation
};
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream>

class Tools {
    public :
      void static sneeze ();
};

void Tools::sneeze ()
{
    std::cout << "atchoum";
}


int main () {
    Tools::sneeze(); // atchoum
}
```

Comment: What about header file? And why not namespace?

Comment: namespace works quite like interfaces, you just gather all the similar-theme functions so you have a space with tools that you can drop in your programs. I'd like that the one who down-rated my post explains why he did so.

Comment: It was not me. But downvote is because your example is bad, I think. You don't use header file. Also you use `class` instead of `namespace`.

Comment: a toolbox is an object right ? a toolbox can be in the namespace 'garage'. plus I just didn't explicitly separate the declarations to each file cause it was shorter and easier to read as it's an example.

Comment: OP's question: `I want to save them so I can use them in any program`. Your example fails to do it. Also, there's no any namespaces or objects in your code. I don't understand what are you talking about. Do you? Don't forget this is C++

Comment: if the reader of the question is a bit inventive and a real programmer, he would quickly know what i was meaning. He just needs to write his own class in the separate c-fashion files like a big boy.
And actually this question is too lame. this question is pretty close than asking how to program in C or C++.